# How to get network manager device name in Qt programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

is there any possibility to get the network adapter device name (network adapter description) using Qt / C++ in windows?

[image]

I used QNetworkInterface, but it return the adapter name only. I want to know which adapter is Ethernet over USB.

```
QNetworkInterface interface;
QList<QNetworkInterface> IpList = interface.allInterfaces();
for (int i = 0; i < IpList.size(); i++)
    qDebug() << "Interface " << i << ":" << IpList.at(i).humanReadableName();
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any possibility to get the network adapter device name
>   (network adapter description) using Qt / C++ in windows

The answer is no. Qt does not have any functionality to get the device name (description). QNetworkInterface can only obtain the interface name and hardware address (IP).

On Windows you can use this small code example. `pAdapter->Description` should hold the value you are looking for.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;
    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *) malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    ULONG buflen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);

    if(GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &buflen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
      free(pAdapterInfo);
      pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *) malloc(buflen);
    }

    if(GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &buflen) == NO_ERROR) {
        PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
        while (pAdapter) {
            printf("\tAdapter Name: \t%s\n", pAdapter->AdapterName);
            printf("\tAdapter Desc: \t%s\n", pAdapter->Description);
            printf("\n\n");
            pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
      }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Example output

```
    Adapter Name:   {DF6051AF-8F8F-4AA8-94A9-34656236F101}
    Adapter Desc:   VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1


    Adapter Name:   {13C8DF49-6D60-4702-9B3A-688B2E372E42}
    Adapter Desc:   TAP-Windows Adapter V9


    Adapter Name:   {42635D10-33A3-4FE9-96BA-1071808B6E2B}
    Adapter Desc:   Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller


    Adapter Name:   {AA62E2BA-D140-4C2C-A1B5-58082ED21E00}
    Adapter Desc:   1 x 1 11b/g/n Wireless LAN PCI Express Half Mini Card-Ad apter


    Adapter Name:   {7AE540D3-69FE-4BEE-A5CA-482CAF06DAB8}
    Adapter Desc:   VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. then I have to search for a 3rd party library. C# has already a builtin library that does the job. maybe I should make a DLL to use it.

Comment: Alex J.: See my updated answer, you can do it yourself in a few lines of code.

Comment: wow, you saved my life! it works perfectly! Many thanks for your support. :-)