# How to retrieve 'device description' for a 'Network adapter' in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, device-manager

Is there any class/routine in Qt that can retrieve the value of 'device description' in 'Network adapters' in 'device manager', see below picture -

[image]

Comment: Qt likely doesn't provide what you are looking for. Best I could find is [QSysInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsysinfo.html), and that just has the bare minimum, nothing network-related.

Comment: You could have a look at [QNetworkInterface::humanReadableName()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html#humanReadableName). It is not exactly what you are looking for, but depending on what you need the name for might be sufficient.

Comment: I recently answered this question. The answer is no. There is no way in Qt. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49952953/3606329